# If I only know a class or ID of a parent element, how can I set a blur listener on a child textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome Extension needs to listen for a blur event on a specific TEXTAREA. The textarea's class and ID are set dynamically by the parent page...so I can't use their details to trigger my content script code.

The textarea is inside a div, however, that does have a fixed class and I can use the blur event listener on this element. However, the div contains other elements and if I only listen to blur on the parent div I can't reliably know when the user moves out of the specific textarea. How can I listen for blur on the child textarea?

Here's some sample code:

```
<div class="parentDIV">
    <input id="checkbox_gidix87dxx">
    <textarea id=textarea_90d9x9ddas">
</div>
```

If I set a focusin event on the parentDIV class I can get the ID of the dynamically created textarea...like this:

```
var ffTextAreaObj = $('.parentDIV').find('textarea');
console.log('Trying for textarea Obj1: ', ffTextAreaObj);
var ffTextAreaID = ffTextAreaObj[0].id;
```

In the focusin listener I tried creating a dynamic listener...but it doesn't fire.

```
$('#' + ffTextAreaID).blur(function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Any help/direction deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I listen for blur on the child textarea?

You can catch changes to the child textarea by setting the blur handler on the parent. The second argument to [jQuery's `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) can be a selector that acts as a filter, so that your handler will only listen to events fired by child elements that match the filter.

The callback function will receive an event object, and you can get the textarea element that fired the event using that object's `.target` property.

```
$(function () {
    $('.parentDIV').on('blur', 'textarea', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah! Okay...I'm actually already using this approach because my listener is at the document level.

I tried to simplify my original example...my actual listener (in content script) is:
$(document).on( 'blur', '.parentDIV', function( e ) {
// DO STUFF
});

Can you add the textarea selector to that statement to limit the blur listener?

Comment: I would try  $(document).on( 'blur', '.parentDIV textarea', function( e ) { // DO STUFF });

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind against some vanilla mixin? ;-) 
Try this:

```js
$('.parentDIV textarea')[0].addEventListener("blur", function(e){
  console.log("Blur has been caught. Blur event: ");
  console.dir(e);
});
```

Does it work?